# jQuery Reel (360 view)- Blurry only on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad

I've been trying to replicate the 360 view of items on the iPad that spins in response to touch events by the finger.  So far, I have been successful in creating it (just copied some code to get started, I'm using the jQuery Reel plugin).  However, the image appears very blurry only when I load it on the iPad.

http://findthetechguy.com/ipadtest3/

However, when I test the original site that I duplicated on the iPad, the reel is much clearer and the images are high-res.

http://www.evoximages.com/products/360-exterior-spin

What is causing my images to lower in quality only on the iPad?  It seems to work fine on my laptop.  Any help would be great.

Comment: I found this in regards to it: "The degraded quality ended up being a limitation the devices have on the size of an uncompressed image in memory. Our jpeg was on average 900 kb’s but it was about 32 mb’s uncompressed in memory, shattering the 8mb limitation."  When I save a file and its about ~1.2 mb, what makes it go over the 8mb limitation?

Comment: Same like with ZIP archives for example, JPEG is also form of compression, so in order to view it, machine has to first decompress it and store the uncompressed data in the memory for us to view. Hence the "inflation".

Answer (score 2):

iOS imposes limits on size of resources in memory (see chapter "Know iOS Resource Limits" of [Safari Web Content Guide](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW15)) causing a known issue of Reel (see [FAQ](http://github.com/pisi/Reel/wiki/FAQ)). What Safari does is it downscales the image in order to fit it into the little chunk of memory dedicated to each resource by the system and displays it that way. This results in different (lower) image dimensions and derails Reel's attempts to use the image sprite. To fight that, Reel uses `-webkit-background-size` CSS directive to enforce the original dimensions in order for frame changing to work correctly, and this is what makes your image look blurry on iPad as a result - your image has been resized down by the system and then back up by Reel.

When this iOS limit is breached, the only option you have is to not use the one sprite image and use individual frame images with `.reel()`'s [`images`](http://bit.ly/reeljs#images) option, which accepts an array of paths to these images.